# At the Sequelize(MySQL), how to use several transactions?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I tried to use Sequelize to put data in the junction table of M:N relationship, but it failed.

The error is detailed below.

At first I thought this problem was in Sequelize's relation model.

However, when I googled it, I thought that it was a problem with the MySQL engine's lock_wait_timeout option, and I looked in various ways to solve it.

I've been told to split the transaction into multiple, but I don't know how to apply it in my code.

Could you show me how?

// error log

```
0|app      |    { Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
0|app      |        at Packet.asError (/home/ec2-user/mepus_test/node_modules/my                                                                                                                                                             sql2/lib/packets/packet.js:712:17)
0|app      |        at Query.execute (/home/ec2-user/mepus_test/node_modules/mys                                                                                                                                                             ql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
0|app      |        at Connection.handlePacket (/home/ec2-user/mepus_test/node_m                                                                                                                                                             odules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:425:32)
0|app      |        at PacketParser.Connection.packetParser.p [as onPacket] (/ho                                                                                                                                                             me/ec2-user/mepus_test/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
0|app      |        at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/ec2-user/mepus_test/node                                                                                                                                                             _modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
0|app      |        at Socket.Connection.stream.on.data (/home/ec2-user/mepus_te                                                                                                                                                             st/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
0|app      |        at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
0|app      |        at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
0|app      |        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
0|app      |        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
0|app      |      code: 'ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT',
0|app      |      errno: 1205,
0|app      |      sqlState: 'HY000',
0|app      |      sqlMessage: 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transa                                                                                                                                                             ction',
0|app      |      sql:
0|app      |       'INSERT INTO `User_Gathering` (`status`,`like`,`book_mark`,`u                                                                                                                                                             ser_idx`,`gathering_idx`) VALUES (1,0,0,1,7);',
0|app      |      parameters: undefined },
```

// routing code

```
let putGathering = async function (req, res) {
    await sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({
                where: {
                    email: req.body.email,
                },
            }, { transaction: transaction });

            const category = await Category.findOne({
                where: {
                    category_name: req.body.categoryName,
                },
            }, { transaction: transaction });

            const [location, created] = await Location.findOrCreate({
                where: {
                    location_name: req.body.meetLoc,
                },
                transaction,
            });

            const gathering = await Gathering.create({
                title: req.body.meetTitle,
                date: req.body.meetDate,
                time: req.body.meetTime,
                content: req.body.content,
                maxnum: req.body.maxNum,
                minnum: req.body.minNum,
                maxage: req.body.maxAge,
                minage: req.body.minAge,
            }, { transaction: transaction });

            await category.addGathering(
                gathering,
                { transaction },
            );

            await location.addGathering(
                gathering,
                { transaction },
            );

            console.log(10);    // This log is worked.

            await gathering.addUser(
                user,
                {
                    through: {
                        status: 1,
                        like: 0,
                        book_mark: 0,
                    }
                },
                { transaction },
            );

            console.log(11);    // This log is not worked. I think there is a problem int upper code.

            res
                .status(201)
                .json({
                    responseMsg: 'succeed',
                })
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
};
```